# Quarto: Persistent problems trying to render/preview

Tags: render, quarto

On Win 7, using R 4.1.2, RStudio 2022.07.1 Build 554, and the latest Quarto (1.0.37),
I am getting persistent errors when I try to build/preview a book project
[**Note added**: I've confirmed the problems described on two other machines, both
Win 10, with the same R & Quarto versions.]

```
**ERROR**: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (os error 32), remove 'C:\Dropbox\Documents\publications\Vis-MLM\site_libs'
```

If it makes any difference, my project is stored in a Dropbox folder.
[**Note added**: This problem does seem to be solved by pausing Dropbox sync as suggested by @user19749376,
but that an unacceptable workflow.]

Then if I restart my session and re-build, the browser opens and I get:

```
Access is denied. (os error 5), stat 'C:\Dropbox\Documents\publications\Vis-MLM\index_files'
```

This 2nd problem is described in [Unable to render quarto in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73247680/unable-to-render-quarto-in-r)
However, I **do** have administrative rights on my computer.

The HTML book, in `_book/` is there, and I can open `index.html` in the browser, however it is
painful to have to do this each time.

Here is **quarto check**

```
[>] Checking Quarto installation......OK
      Version: 1.0.37
      Path: C:\Program Files\Quarto\bin\
      CodePage: 1252

[>] Checking basic markdown render....OK

[>] Checking Python 3 installation....(None)

      Unable to locate an installed version of Python 3.
      Install Python 3 from https://www.python.org/downloads/

[>] Checking R installation...........OK
      Version: 4.1.2
      Path: C:/R/R-4.1.2
      LibPaths:
        - C:/R/R-4.1.2/library
      rmarkdown: 2.14

[>] Checking Knitr engine render......OK
```

I'd be grateful for any help solving this.  I'm nearly at my wits end with Quarto.

Comment: I protected this question to prevent more "I successfully used the exact same solution on a different platform." kind of non-answers - at least by officially unexperienced users.

Answer (score 3):

I'm experiencing the same error message ("ERROR: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (os error 32)" and am fairly certain it is caused by Dropbox accessing some of the files for syncing while quarto renders the book project and tries to remove the files again in the process as the error message does not appear anymore once I pause Dropbox syncing. Are you observing the same?

Unfortunately, at least for me, that's not really a sustainable solution as I'd like things to be synced to Dropbox but maybe it helps with finding a workaround or settings that can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue working out of Google Drive, which I had solved by just working out of a local folder on my PC. Perhaps your working directory could be locally on your PC and then you can move the document to Dropbox after completion?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue working on a cloud drive, but copying the working dir to local drive resolved the issue. Hopefully Quarto will work with cloud drives in the future.

Comment: Please make more obvious what additional insight you contribute beyond existing answers. Otherwise this is perceived as a "thanks" non-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing here (with the message *Input/output error (os error 5), remove **file/path** files*) using [pcloud](https://www.pcloud.com/) in linux (kubuntu). Then I move the files to a local folder and it worked fine.

Comment: Please make more obvious what additional insight you contribute beyond existing answers. Otherwise this is perceived as a "thanks" non-answer.

Comment: My contribution was to inform that using pcloud (system), occurs the same issue. But anyways I add the link and made the text more obvious. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I remember also adding OS and message info. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: Still "also observed in a different environment (with details which one), with the same solution already described here".

Comment: Yes, that is the case, as indicated by other contributors on the topic.

Comment: True, I commented accordingly on the one with the same problem.

Comment: So, beyond the editions that I did, still not clear to me, what is your suggestion?

Comment: Consider turning this into a comment. And/or to delete it.